# Why do the configurations options change after a build attempt, on OpenShift?

Tags: laravel-5, openshift, bitbucket

Novice here, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Got myself an [OpenShift Starter Online] account, bitbucket with my code, and I'm trying to follow this quickstart: https://github.com/luciddreamz/laravel-ex/blob/master/readme.md

When I create the project, I am able to configure the Build YAML, and put in the paramaters of my bitbucket repo.

The build fails with "Assemble fail" error.

When I go back to look at my build YAML, it's now all different, like it's been totally overwritten.

-confused-

*Edit*

BEFORE INITIATING THE BUILD

```
...
spec:
  triggers:
    - type: ImageChange
      imageChange:
        lastTriggeredImageID: >-
          registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/php-70-******
    - type: ConfigChange
    - type: GitHub
      github:
        secret: ************
  runPolicy: Serial
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: 'https://**************git'
  strategy:
    type: Source
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        namespace: openshift
        name: 'php:7.0'
      env:
        - name: COMPOSER_MIRROR
  output:
```

AFTER THE BUILD

```
...
spec:
  triggers:
    - type: ImageChange
      imageChange:
        lastTriggeredImageID: >-
          registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/php-70-********
    - type: ConfigChange
  runPolicy: Serial
  source:
    type: None
  strategy:
    type: Source
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        namespace: openshift
        name: 'php:7.0'
      env:
        - name: COMPOSER_MIRROR
  output:
```

Comment: How you are creating the application build configuration and deployment in OpenShift to begin with? Are you using ``oc new-app``, ``oc new-build``, ``oc create`` from a resource file? When you load a build configuration from a file, then OpenShift will add additional fields and possibly update some as well if they reflected state that actually changes.

Comment: Just using the web console.

Comment: Better explain what you mean by 'totally overwritten'? Show what the YAML looked liked before for section you say is being rewritten, and then what it gets rewritten to. Just mask any sensitive stuff like URLs to repos or other secret information. If can't see what you see, can't really help too much. Do keep in mind that if you are putting configuration information in wrong places in the YAML, it will be dropped and lost, so make sure you are changing the correct parts.

Comment: Ok, "totally overwritten" is an exageration - it's the source section that bothers me. I set it up, the build fails, I go back to edit it, but now the source is no longer defined. I think I'll give the pure CLI approach a go, rather than using the web console, and see what that does.